# Does the concept of Naysmith exist outside the Warhammer universe?

Tags: history-of, warhammer-40k

In *Horus Rising* by Dan Abnett, they introduce the concept of the Naysmith:

> ‘Then it occurs to me, Garviel, that only a weapon which questions its use could be of any value in that role. To be a member of the Mournival, you need to have concerns. You need to have wit, and most certainly you need to have doubts. Do you know what a nay-smith is?’
>
> ‘No.’
>
> ‘In early Terran history, during the dominance of the Sumaturan dynasts, naysmiths were employed by the ruling classes. Their job was to disagree. To question everything. To consider any argument or policy and find fault with it, or articulate the counter position. They were highly valued.’

The [I found a reference to ‘naysmith’ in a work of science fiction. Is anybody familiar with the term?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/501319/i-found-a-reference-to-naysmith-in-a-work-of-science-fiction-is-anybody-famil) question in the *English Language & Usage SE* states there is no real world source for this term and that [it might be a tribute to *Bob Naismith*, a miniature designer in the 80s](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/530306).

However, the concept of having an advisor that disagrees and finds faults sounds very useful to me. So, I've begun to search if I was able to find a real world application or another work of fiction using that concept but was not able find anything. Is there any other universe, including our own, that uses advisors with such a job description? Was this before or after the introduction of the Naysmith in Warhammer (April 2006, as far as I was able to find out)?

Comment: See also: [Devil's Advocate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil%27s_advocate)

Comment: The term "naysmith" may not be used, but this is pretty much the entire purpose of the [official opposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Her_Majesty%27s_Most_Loyal_Opposition_(United_Kingdom)) in UK government, and probably other countries with a similar political system.

Comment: Maybe worth asking on History.SE

Comment: Given that "nay" is archaic English for "no", originating with Old Norse "ne", and "smith" has a similar origin in "smiðr", the claim of a Sumatran dynasty naming their loyal oppositionists and fault-finders "nay-smiths" seems clearly invented. In archaic English use, a naysmith is another term for a cutler, or one who smiths table cutlery.

Comment: It could also be a bit of a deliberate bastardisation of “naysayer” a play on the fact that a lot of the old Earth words are always slightly misspelt due to a lack of knowledge of “our time”

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's an idiom in English: a "devil's advocate" - someone who pretends, in an argument or discussion, to be against an idea or plan that a lot of people support, in order to promote discussion on the subject.

This idiom, apparently, originates in an [office](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil%27s_advocate) in catholic church, which role was to argue against a candidate for canonisation. It was complemented by the office of "God's advocate", whose role was to provide evidence to the contrary. The office was created in 1587, but there are mentions of people performing the same function in same context before that.

Note that both in context of Catholic church office and modern idiom, "devil's advocate" is not supposed to be a full-time job; this role would be temporarily performed by a specialist in the field who is available at the moment or an outside expert specially invited for the task.

Two in-universe points are also important to consider: one, the knowledge Imperium of Man has of "early Terran history" (or, well, *any* history of events before the Great Crusade) is often hazy and distorted, so linking it to any prototype in our world can be tough; two - so-called "Age of Terra" is defined as the time between 1st and 15th milleniums (that means from 1 A.D. to 14999 A.D.), which means that "early Terran history" could well mean 4th millenium (i.e. long past our time).

Comment: Israeli intelligence even has a [Devil's Advocate Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Devil%27s_Advocate_Unit), whose purpose is quite close to the Naysmith's role.

Answer (score 1):

There is something like that in [*Master of the Etrax*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?651129), a 1970 fantasy novel by [Robert Lory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_Lory). The main character, Hamper by name, is a court offical called the Left-Hand Advocate or the However, whose function is like that of a "Naysmith". An excerpt was published as the novelette ["However"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?559801) in [*Worlds of Fantasy* #1, 1968](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?185669), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Worlds_Of_Fantasy_v01n01_1968_EXciter/page/n97/mode/2up).

Blurb from [the 2014 BookBaby ebook](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?469264) of *Master of the Etrax*:

> When your job duties demand you be the least popular official in the throne room, don't be surprised by who draws the next really nasty assignment!

From the excerpt "However" in *Worlds of Fantasy*:

> *Forenote: It is recorded that the kingdom of Batik had an official However of exceptional ability. Every king, of course, is in need of someone to however at all times. But strangely, few Howevers are truly popular with their monarchs.*
>
> *Hence, when the call came from the country of Overnon asking for a messenger on an important mission, the king of Balik was less loathe* [sic] *to release Hamper the However than might have been supposed.*

From Chapter 1 of *Master of the Etrax*:

> At the Table of Decision in the ante-throne room of Castle Bolsk, Aufcash III, High Hodgepoker over Balik's five provinces, concluded his opening remarks. Cocking his dignified head to his left, he gave the nod of speech allowance to the court's Left-Hand Advocate, otherwise called the However.
>
> "Noble Aufcash," Hamper began once on his feet—or, rather, foot and peg leg—"it is true as you say that war is a noble enterprise. It is true as you say that our five provinces have not been engaged in such a noble enterprise since your illustrious ancestor, Aufcash I, overthrew the yoke of the Philosopher Rai, devil of devils. It is true as you say that peace rusts our weapons. *However,* while I certainly understand how all of these truths can be unpleasant to a fierce and valiant warrior as you potentially are—however unproven—may I point out, Lord Hodgepoker, that no enemy has presented itself shields a-banging at the foot of Castle Bolsk. To make war may well be worthy—however, it requires a foe."
>
> The High Hodgepoker nodded, then turned to his right. He nodded again, and recognizing the signal, a tall gaunt nobleman of past middle age, balding in three different areas of his head, rose.
>
> "Nonetheless," said Nuygrov the Nonetheless, or Right-Hand Advocate, "our High Hodgepoker's arguments are weighty."
>
> "I do not deny that," replied Hamper. "I would point out to you, however, that the snarl-mammoth is weighty also. This singular fact does not always assure he won't misstep now and then and disappear into a crack in the earth."
>
> "Nonetheless," retorted Nuygrov, "our High Hodgepoker wishes war."
>
> A slight man sitting to the right of Nuygrov now rose. This was Melton the Moreover, or Assistant to the Right-Hand Advocate. There traditionally was no assistant to the Left-Hand Advocate.
>
> "Moreover—if I may add a word?" he said inquiringly.
>
> "Do," urged Nuygrov.
>
> "Moreover," Melton began again, "what the High Hodgepoker wishes, it is the duty of this council to bring to reality."
>
> "May I suggest to the council," said Trowl the Suggestor from the far end of the table, "that we simply shall have to find an enemy worthy of Balik's steel."
>
> "A sound suggestion," Hamper responded. "However, in such a quest it is possible to be oversuccessful and find an enemy which is more than worthy of Balik's steel."
>
> Silence greeted the However's statement.